# Выход ракетки за границы сцены в игре пинг понг юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

При создании 2D игры по типу пинг понг на Юнити возникла проблема связанная с частичным выходом двух ракеток за поля сцены, причем если обе ракетки медленно подходят к нижнему и верхнему краю сцены они не выходят за границы, но с увеличением скорости их движения иногда такое происходит.  Код отвечающий за движение ракеток ниже:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pad : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float speed;

    float height;
    string inpt;
    public bool isRightPad;

    // Вызывается в начале игры, перед первым обновлением кадра
    void Start()
    {
        height = transform.localScale.y;
    }

    public void Init(bool isRight)
    {
        isRightPad = isRight;
        Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;

        // Обрабатываем изменение позиции ракетки. Для левой и правой ракетки - отдельно.
        if (isRight)
        {
            pos = new Vector2(GameManager.topRight.x, 0);
            pos -= Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x;
            inpt = "PadRight";
        } else {
            pos = new Vector2(GameManager.bottomLeft.x, 0);
            pos += Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x;
            inpt = "PadLeft";
        }

        transform.position = pos;
        transform.name = inpt;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Блокируем выход ракетки за края экрана, обрабатываем изменение позиции на экране
        float move = UnityEngine.Input.GetAxis(inpt) * Time.deltaTime * speed;

        if(transform.position.y < GameManager.bottomLeft.y + height/2 && move < 0)
        {
            move = 0;
        }

        if (transform.position.y > GameManager.topRight.y - height / 2 && move > 0)
        {
            move = 0;
        }

        transform.Translate(move * Vector2.up);
    }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема и какие возможны варианты ее решения? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Статика тут не нужна и ее легко избежать.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Board : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _size = new Vector2(10, 6);
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _ancore = Vector2.zero;

    public Vector2 Size => _size;
    public Vector2 Ancore => _ancore;
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Pad : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public float Velocity = 0;
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 1;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _size = new Vector2(0.5f, 1);
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private Board _board;
    private Transform _transform;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        _transform = transform;
        ToSideBorder();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    private void Move () 
    {
        _transform.position += new Vector3(0, Velocity*_speed*Time.deltaTime, 0);
        CheckBorders();
    }

    private void CheckBorders ()
    {
        Vector3 position = _transform.position;
        float min = _board.Ancore.y+(-_board.Size.x+_size.y)*0.5f;
        float max = _board.Ancore.y+(_board.Size.x-_size.y)*0.5f;
        position.y = Mathf.Clamp(position.y, min, max);
        _transform.position = position;
    }

    private void ToSideBorder () 
    {
        if (_transform.position.x < _board.Ancore.x)
            _transform.position = _board.Ancore+new Vector2((-_board.Size.x+_size.x)*0.5f, 0);
        else
            _transform.position = _board.Ancore+new Vector2((_board.Size.x-_size.x)*0.5f, 0);
    }
}
```

---

Управление это отдельная ответственность.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Pad))]

public class PadPlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _axisName = "Vertical";
    private Pad _pad;

    private void Start () 
    {
        _pad = GetComponent<Pad>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float axis = Input.GetAxis(_axisName);
        _pad.Velocity = axis;
    }
}
```